# Unable to match Indian Rupee currency symbol using regex in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, unicode

Following is my text:

```
Total: ₹ 131.84

Thanks for choosing Uber, Pradeep
```

I would like to match the amount part, using the following code:

```
if ( $mail_body =~ /Total: \x{20B9} (\d+)/ ) {
    $amount = $1;
}
```

But, it does not match, tried using regex debugging, here's the output:

```
Compiling REx "Total: \x{20B9} (\d+)"
Final program:
   1: EXACT <Total: \x{20b9} > (5)
   5: OPEN1 (7)
   7:   PLUS (9)
   8:     DIGIT (0)
   9: CLOSE1 (11)
  11: END (0)
anchored utf8 "Total: %x{20b9} " at 0 (checking anchored) minlen 10
Matching REx "Total: \x{20B9} (\d+)" against "Total: %342%202%271%302%240131.84%n%nThanks for choosing Ube"...
UTF-8 pattern...
Match failed
Freeing REx: "Total: \x{20B9} (\d+)"
```

The full code is at http://pastebin.com/TGdFX7hg.

Comment: What does `$mail_body` look like if you output it?

Comment: It is showing a match here: https://regex101.com/r/iO5aL8/2

Comment: @karthikmanchala that is php's pcre regex engine and you just copied the text the OP copied in here, most likely from his email program. Perl's internal regex engine is a different story, and the content of OP's variable is not necessarily the same as the email program lets them copy.

Comment: @simbabque pcre means "perl compatible regular expressions", which should work with perl's internal regex engine.

Comment: @karthikmanchala I know. But it's _compatible_. Not the same.

Comment: You can actually use `/Total:\s+\xE2\x82\xB9\s+(\d+)/`.

Comment: %342%202%271%302%240 translates to e2 82 b9 c2 a0, so @stribizhev's method should work. Side note: (\d+(.\d*)?) captures also the parts after the comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Disclaimer:* This feels more like a comment than an answer, but I need more space.

I've never used [`MIME::Parser`](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Parser) and friends before, but from what I've read in the documentation, the following might work:

```
use Encode qw(decode);

# according to your code, $text_mail is a MIME::Entity object
my $charset = $text_mail->head->mime_attr('content-type.charset');
my $mail_body_raw = $text_mail->bodyhandle->as_string;

my $mail_body = decode $charset, $mail_body_raw;
```

The idea is to get the charset from the `MIME::Head` object, then use [`Encode`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode) to decode the body accordingly.

Of course, if you know that it's always going to be UTF-8 text, you could also hardcode that:

```
my $mail_body = decode 'UTF-8', $mail_body_raw;
```

---

After that, your regex may still fail to work because according to the debugging output in your question the character between ₹ and the number is actually not a simple space (ASCII 32, U+0020), but a non-breaking space (U+00A0). You should be able to match that with `\s`:

```
if ( $mail_body =~ /Total: \x{20B9}\s(\d+)/ ) {
```

Comment: Thanks @melpomene used decode sub-routine and used this "$mail_body =~ /Total: \x{20B9}(?:\x{00A0}|\x{C2A0}|\s)(\d+(.\d*)?)/" Works!

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of searching for the explanation, not an outright answer. Please bear with me.

---

I believe your `$mail_body` does not contain what you think it does. You posted the input data as plain text. Was that copied from a mail client?

If I take the code and the input data from the question and run it with `use re 'debug'` I get a different output.

```
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;
use re 'debug';

my $mail_body = qq{Total: ₹ 131.84

Thanks for choosing Uber, Pradeep};

if ( $mail_body =~ /Total: \x{20B9} (\d+)/ ) {
    my $amount = $1;
}
```

It will produce this:

```
Compiling REx "Total: \x{20B9} (\d+)"
Final program:
   1: EXACT <Total: \x{20b9} > (5)
   5: OPEN1 (7)
   7:   PLUS (9)
   8:     POSIXU[\d] (0)
   9: CLOSE1 (11)
  11: END (0)
anchored utf8 "Total: %x{20b9} " at 0 (checking anchored) minlen 10 
Matching REx "Total: \x{20B9} (\d+)" against "Total: %x{20b9} 131.84%n%nThanks for choosing Uber, Pradeep"
UTF-8 pattern and string...
Intuit: trying to determine minimum start position...
  Found anchored substr "Total: %x{20b9} " at offset 0...
  (multiline anchor test skipped)
Intuit: Successfully guessed: match at offset 0
   0 <> <Total: >            |  1:EXACT <Total: \x{20b9} >(5)
  11 < %x{20b9} > <131.84%n%n>|  5:OPEN1(7)
  11 < %x{20b9} > <131.84%n%n>|  7:PLUS(9)
                                  POSIXU[\d] can match 3 times out of 2147483647...
  14 <%x{20b9} 131> <.84%n%nTha>|  9:  CLOSE1(11)
  14 <%x{20b9} 131> <.84%n%nTha>| 11:  END(0)
Match successful!
Freeing REx: "Total: \x{20B9} (\d+)"
```

Let's compare the line with the *Matching REx* to your output:

```
against against "Total: %x{20b9} 131.84%n%nThanks for choosing Uber, Pradeep"
against "Total: %342%202%271%302%240131.84%n%nThanks for choosing Ube"...
```

As we can see, there my output has `%x{e2}` and so on, while yours has `%342`.

When I started trying this code I forgot to put `use utf8` in my code, so I got a bunch of single characters when the regex engine tried to match:

```
%x{e2}%x{82}%x{b9}
```

It then rejected the match.

So my conclusion is: **Perl doesn't know your input data is utf8.**

Comment: Yeah, the issue is that wherever that data is coming from, it wasn't decoded (and so is still a bunch of bytes, not unicode text).

Comment: Thanks, how do I fix this?

Comment: @Pradeep Where does your text (`$mail_body`) come from?

Comment: @Pradeep: you can take a look at this module to try to find the current encoding: http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode/Guess.html and convert it to utf8

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Ew. You should never guess encodings if you can avoid it.